# Unable to read all Serial Port data, having Baud rate 3000000

Tags: c#, serial-port, port

We are reading the data on a COM Port using System.IO.Ports => SerialPort class.
But when trying to read the data for Baud rate 3M it skip a few lines of data.

However, when using the other applications (e.g TeraTerm or SmarTTY app) to read the data, we can read all the data.

Can someone help me to know how to read the data using C# Serial Port class for such high baud rate.
For lower baud rate, I did not find any issue in data receive.

**Code Sample:**

```
SerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Port_DataReceived);
                

private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
            string line = null;
            line = DeviceUSBSerialPort.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Do you know the device capabilities of your hardware?  The driver associated will define the maximum allowed baud.

Comment: Why not try changing the [ReadBufferSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to a huge size or using [ReadExisting()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instead of ReadLine()?

Comment: @Greg Thanks for reply, but as I mentioned above hard is configured to allow this baud rate, because logging is working on Tera Term and SmartTTY.